# Analytic solution for non-flat filter design

Tags: filter-design

I'm trying to write an accelerometer calibration script that uses filters to convert from volts into $m/s^2$.  As accelerometers tend to have non-flat response curves, this means I have to design a rather complex filter.  I'm not worried about phase, as I can just apply the filter twice in opposing directions to correct for any phase offsets (like matlab's `filtfilt`), so the focus is on designing a filter that approximates a user-provided magnitude curve.

Ideally, the user provides a calibration curve as input into an analytic algorithm to solve for the best fitting filter poles.

I'm aware MATLAB has a filter design function, but I don't know what the underlying algorithm is (if its an optimizer, or a closed form solution).

So my question is...

- Is there an analytic solution to my filter design problem?  Or do I have to use optimisation scripts to get the best filter?

I'm not mentioning programming language here, as I want to understand the underlying math behind this.

Comment: Okay... I think I answered my own question.  What I was searching for is essentially _linear-phase FIR filter design by least squares_.  [This document](http://eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/EL713/firls/firls.pdf) seems to cover the theory behind it.

Comment: Another easy simple method to do this is to populated a large FFT grid with your target amplitude, do an inverse FFT and then time window or gate the impulse response to the desired accuracy.

Comment: @Hilmar, that sounds great!  I'm guessing the benefit of the least squares approach is that I can force the design of a _linear phase filter_... but if I use the `filtfilt` approach to applying my filter, this would not be a concern for me, and it would result in a more accurately matched spectrum magnitude.  If you post this as an answer (and i verify it works as expected), I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not concerned on the phase and just want to approximate a magnitude response, then your first option should be the **frequency sampling** method implemented in Matlab/Octave fir2() function.

You would provide the frequency grid and corresponding frequency response magnitude at those frequencies.

As you have also mentioned, least-squares approach is another alternative. Indeed by using suitable weights, you can distribute the error according to your priority cirteria.

Magnitude approximation based on LMS adaptive system identification is also a possible option.

Comment: Am i right in understanding **frequency sampling** is essentially what @Hilmar was suggesting in their comment?  Or is there something a bit more intricate to it?

Comment: Speaking of Matlab fir2() ;They should be essentially the same (possibly exact same things); both are based on inverse FFT of the specified magnitude response. You may check its documentation to see if there's anything intricate other than indicated in his comment.

Comment: Reading into this more...  The difference between this answers suggestion and Hilmar's comment above (just do an ifft of the desired response), is that the method proposed here (Matlab's `fir2`) applies a window function to reduce rippling in the frequency response after the ifft.  Otherwise, the methods are the same.  This [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31905/difference-between-frequency-sampling-and-windowing-method) goes into detail on how the windowing affects the filter.